# SSH Gitlab clone asking for password

Tags: git, gitlab

I am trying to clone a repository from my universities gitlab and after entering the command it is asking for a password.

```
 git clone git@osgit.rnet.university.edu:os/sp18/Assignment1

 Cloning into 'Assignment1_CRefresher_user'...
 git@osgit.rnet.university.edu's password:
```

I am not figuring out how to get past this step what password is it asking for? I have an SSH key pair generated on my gitlab profile is that that the issueand what I need to connect to my personal computer in some way?

Comment: Talk to the people who run the repo.  (Or read the instructions again ....)  I don't think we are in a position to guess how you should be accessing that repo.

Comment: FWIW: It might be asking for the password on the `git` account, or there may not be a `git` account at all ... and you are seeing the standard behaviour that happens when you try to authenticate with an unknown account.  Or something else.

Comment: If this is an actual gitlab instance, you need to log into the web interface and add an ssh public key to your account.  Presumably someone somewhere has provided instructions on how to do this,because otherwise nobody is going to finish `Assignment1`.

Comment: @larsks yeah I believe something similar to this was my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I believe I was not inside my instance when the SSH key was created. it should only ask for a password if there is no key.

Sorry if I wasted anybody's time thank you